# Foundation Libsass workflow

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, libsass

I'm new to Sass and I'm having some trouble with workflow.

For instance, I've tried to position nav section a little bit lower. I managed that by creating new _style.scss and importing it in app.scss. This is the code from new file:

```
//* _style.scss
.top-bar-section {
    padding-top: 1.1875rem;
    }
```

It works, but when I try other things, I cannot override values from _top-bar.scss (there was no padding for .top-bar-section).

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Could I (should I) make the changes in _settings.scss? Trouble is, I can't find the corresponding variable.

And if I understand correctly, I can't make changes in /bower_components.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out Foundation has dedicated app.scss for this.

So, you edit in settings.scss (here you make changes to what's already been styled) and app.scss (here you make your own additional styling).